# Electron - Resize Window from renderer process

Tags: javascript, resize, electron

I am working on an Electron app and as part of the interface I want to increase the size of the window once something has happened (I have bound this to a button for now) so I can display additional data. I have attempted to do this with the following code that is activated on a `onclick=resize()`:

```
require('./renderer.js');

let remote = require('electron').remote;
function resize() {
    let win = remote.getCurrentWindow().setBounds({
        height: 1000
    });
}
```

However, I am getting the following error in the window/browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not call remote function 'setBounds'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from #<Object>
Error: Could not call remote function 'setBounds'. Check that the function signature is correct. Underlying error: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from #<Object>
    at callFunction (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\rpc-server.js:257:11)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\rpc-server.js:357:5)
    at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:204:7)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:256:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at callFunction (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\rpc-server.js:257:11)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\rpc-server.js:357:5)
    at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:204:7)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:256:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at metaToValue (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\api\remote.js:234:13)
    at Object.remoteMemberFunction (C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\api\remote.js:118:18)
    at resize (file:///D:/Documents/Development/Projects/ShortenMeURL/V1/index.html:41:45)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (file:///D:/Documents/Development/Projects/ShortenMeURL/V1/index.html:22:86)
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried providing every props for rectangular object? Docs doesn't mark any prop as optional. And have you tried `setSize(w, h)`?

Comment: @pergy that worked, thanks. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can give you the rep, etc.

Comment: Glad to hear! ;) posted it as answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definition of [`Rectangle`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/rectangle) object (which is the first argument of [`setBounds`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetboundsbounds-animate)) is more strict than you expected. Since its properties don't have default values you have to define all of them.

For example:

```
remote.getCurrentWindow().setBounds({
    x: 1621,
    y: 611,
    width: 10,
    height: 1000
});
```

Also, if you want to adjust only size you can use [`setSize`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetsizewidth-height-animate) of BrowserWindow

Answer (score 3):

Just use plain old javascript from the renderer, I would not add an unnecessary messaging between main and renderer process if it is just a resize ;)

```
window.resizeTo(1000,900);
```

Comment: any idea how to make the electron browser window responsive to the content?

Comment: `MutationObserver` on the body element then `resizeTo` @oldboy

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's getting a similar error, make sure you provide integer values, for example `123`, not `123,45`. `Math.round` them to make sure.

I don't see a mention of this in the documentation sadly.